# How to achieve multi-line prints using the print() inside a user defined function?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, indentation

**MY CODE**

```
def SimplePrint():
    print("""LINE 1
    LINE 2
    LINE 3""")


SimplePrint()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
LINE 1
    LINE 2
    LINE 3
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
```

It Works When I Make The Following Changes To My Code :

```
def SimplePrint():
    print("""LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3""")


SimplePrint()
```

This However, Disturbs The Indentation.
I Was Wondering If There's Another Way To Do It.

Comment: Indentation within strings belongs to strings.

Comment: @DYZ I understand, I do not want to use `\n` either. I was just wondering if there's a better way to do it as it would improve the readability.

Comment: You either type the string verbatim or use "\n" or print each line separately. There is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the IDE add the indentation when you press `Enter` but your python multi line(i.e triple quote) string which is one single string treat the indentation added by the IDE as part of it's literal behavior.

Understand it this way **IDE add the space or tab automatically but python interpreter treat that indentation as space or tab due to multiline string**.

```
           print("""this is demo
<space/tab>behavior of multi line string""")
```

Solution: Just escape that indentation added by IDE automatically.

```
           print("""this is happy demo
behavior of multi line string""")
```